# Make hierarchy list with recursion function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, rdflib

I'm new to python. I'm trying to make a list representing hierarchical data starting from some node, queried from a graph with rdflib.

Here is the input file:

```
    @prefix ex: <http://www.w3.org/1/> .
    ex:b1 ex:rel ex:a .
    ex:b2 ex:rel ex:a .
    ex:c ex:rel ex:b1 .
```

And here is the code:

```
    from rdflib import Graph, Literal, BNode, Namespace, RDF, URIRef
    from sets import Set
    g = Graph()
    g.parse("test.ttl", format="turtle")
    ex = Namespace('http://www.w3.org/1/')
    dlist = []
    def totree(lst):
        global dlist
        if dlist == []:
           dlist.append(lst)
        for i in lst:
            for s, p, o in g.triples((None, ex.rel, URIRef(ex + i))):
                s = str(BNode(s)).replace(ex, '')
                g.remove((s, p, o))
                dlist.append([s])
                totree([s])
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        totree(['a'])
    print dlist
```

And i get this output:

```
    [['a'], [u'b1'], [u'c'], [u'b2']]
```

How can I output a hierarchical list as in :

```
    [['a', [u'b1', [u'c']], [u'b2']]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your input inside a tree